# Apollo Android GraphQL client - Duplicate code generation for same responses

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm currently using Apollo's Android GraphQL client to interact with our GraphQL server. I have several queries and mutations defined in my graphql file. A couple of them return same data structure in the response. However, the code that's autogenerated by Apollo results in different data classes.

For example I have the following mutations:

```
mutation completeLogin(...) {
    loginComplete(input: ...) {
        login {
            token {
                access_token
                refresh_token
            }
        }
    }
}

mutation createPassword(...) {
    createPassword(input: ...) {
        login {
            token {
                access_token
                refresh_token
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The autogenerated classes for these are as follows:

```
data class CompleteLoginMutation{

    //...

  data class Login(
    val token: Token
  )
  data class Token(
    val access_token: String,
    val refresh_token: String
  )
}

data class CreatePasswordMutation{

    //...

  data class Login(
    val token: Token
  )
  data class Token(
    val access_token: String,
    val refresh_token: String
  )
}
```

I was expecting that `Login` or `Token` classes in these autogenerated classes were mapped to the same class as they are actually the same on the backend side. This is a problem while implementing mappers that convert data entities to domain entities. I need to implement the same mapper for these classes separately, resulting in further duplication. Is there a way to map the same query/mutation responses to the same autogenerated classes in GraphQL or may Apollo client be capable of such convenience?

Comment: use fragments ?

Comment: fragments don't prevent generation of duplicate classes.

Comment: on login? I don't think it's supported for nested (why not just one level - token?) class ... or it should work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605813/6124657 ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Each mutation data class has its own "Login" and "Token". I want them to be generated as common data classes.

Comment: server return type for this mutations? it's one type (Login?) ... querying nested data (Token) doesn't matter  ... how did you try to implement fragments?

Comment: Yes it's same "Login" on server side. But on Android side, it's "CompleteLoginMutation.Login" and "CreatePasswordMutation.Login". This is the problem.

Comment: I mean **graphql type** (not java class) ... is it defined in API as `Login`, is it mutation return type? is it discoverable by introspection query? `createPassword(input: CreatePasswordMutationInput): LOGIN` ???

Comment: Both mutations return this:  type LoginCompleteResponse { login: LoginComplete! }

Comment: then you can use `fragment loginFragment on LoginCompleteResponse ...`

Comment: this doesnt resolve duplication issue. fragments only resolve duplication in graphql files. if I use fragments, the generated class becomes CompleteLoginMutation.Fragments.Login.Token. Still connected to CompleteLoginMutation.

Comment: why not simply LoginFragment? it should work with fragments ... if not, post an issue on github ... with full description ... again, how are you trying fragments? without subprops/subtypes I hope?